# How to format a date in PHP without a colon in the offset?

Tags: php, timezone

So I've got this:

`date('c')`

which formats it like so:

`2010-08-17T08:55:14-07:00`

but I need a way to not have the colon in the offset, so maybe it would look like this:

`2010-08-17T08:55:14-0700`

What solution is there for this? I'm hoping for a slightly different format, rather than getting the string and replacing the last colon (using reg-ex or something).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build it up from the constituent parts:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO')
```

See the [`date`](http://php.net/date) documentation for the different format strings.

The one you're interested in is `O`:

> Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours (Example: +0200)

Instead of `P`:

> Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)  (Example: +02:00)

Answer (score 16):

Interestingly, `date(DATE_ISO8601)` doesn't give you the colon.

but `date('c')` does, and the manual states (for 'c'):

> ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)

Comment: That's the beauty of PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PHP's [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and try to find other options.

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');  //2010-08-17T08:55:14-0700
```