# How do I convert datetime to ISO 8601 in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, datetime-format, time-format

How do I convert my time from `2010-12-30 23:21:46` to ISO 8601 date format? (-_-;)

Comment: @Gordon yes I got [about 4,530 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+datetime+to+ISO+8601+site:stackoverflow.com) and I found answer from @alex

Comment: @wow please point out why none of the 4530 results answered your question.

Comment: @Gordon I'm still learning how to write from A to Z but I found they teach me how to write from Z to A :)

Comment: @wow No. They teach you how to write alphabet($from, $to). Almost all of them tell you to use `date($format, strtotime($dateString))` or the `DateTime` object equivalent. They only differ in the input to those functions. All you have to do is [go to the correponding pages in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and find out what the input is.

Comment: @Gordon Yes are you correct. I just knew the alphabet and now spelling bee time. Hope I'm in the right school.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

#### Object Oriented

This is the recommended way.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2010-12-30 23:21:46');

echo $datetime->format(DateTime::ATOM); // Updated ISO8601
```

---

#### Procedural

For older versions of PHP, or if you are more comfortable with procedural code.

```
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46'));
```

Comment: Question, the output is `2010-12-30T23:21:46+1100` how to make it to be `2010-12-30T23:21:46+11:00`?

Comment: @wow Try this `preg_replace('/(?<=\d{2})(?=\d{2}$)/', ':', '2010-12-30T23:21:46+1100')`. It outputs `2010-12-30T23:21:46+11:00`.

Comment: [`echo date('c', …` produces the output with the colon.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504476/help-me-with-formatting-a-date/3504534#3504534)

Comment: @Gordon Interesting, I never knew that.

Comment: `date('c', strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46'))` nice @Gordon :)

Comment: I would note that using `DATE_ISO8601` produces a date string which is slightly different than ISO8601 (the colon is missing in the TZ, ISO8601 expects times to be all with OR all without the colon, not a mixture) - `date('c')` does produces a strict ISO 8601 valid date - This could cause hard to trace bugs if code expects a strict ISO 8601 datetime format. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @ckm Nowhere does it read that if colons are used to separate the time components, that the timezone designator must follow suit.

Comment: DATE_ISO8601 causes problems with JavaScript as ECMAScript Language Specification requires `HH:mm`
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

Comment: @alex, for some reason the constant ISO8601 is not compatible with ISO-8601, use `DateTime::ATOM` instead, see the note in http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601

Comment: How to remove seconds from the first method. Its giving me output : 2017-03-18T11:30:00+00:00. But I need : 2017-03-18T11:30+00:00.

Comment: I love this gem from the PHP documentation: "DATE_ISO8601 [...] Note: This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use DateTime::ATOM or DATE_ATOM for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead."

Comment: Keep in mind that strtotime() will convert a date according to the PHP timezone setting

Comment: Note for JetBrains IDE users: ATOM is currently **incorrectly** marked as removed since PHP 7.2. Bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59894

Comment: It's better to refer to `DateTimeInterface::ATOM` rather than a child class.

Answer (score 50):

After PHP 5 you can use this: `echo date("c");` form ISO 8601 formatted datetime.

http://ideone.com/nD7piL

Note for comments:

Regarding to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC), both of these expressions are valid for timezone, for basic format: `±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh]`.

But note that, +0X:00 is correct, and +0X00 is incorrect for extended usage. So it's better to use `date("c")`. A similar discussion [here](http://php.net/manual/tr/class.datetime.php#116085).

Comment: Note the slight difference with `DATE_ISO8601`; `+0X:00` vs `+0X00`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck does this need down-voting, then? A slight difference is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @rybo111 I don't see a reason to down-vote this answer; technically, both `'c'` and `DATE_ISO8601` produce valid ISO8601 time representations.

Comment: I added a note to answer.

Comment: @Ja͢ck `DATE_ISO8601` does not produce a valid ISO8601 representation. DATE_ATOM does though

Comment: @LeeButler is there a bug report for reference?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I'm not sure, but it's documented in the Php docs that it's not quite compatible.

Comment: @LeeButler with that naming of the constant, it seems reason enough to classify it as a bug

Comment: I agree with @LeeButler, the DATE_ISO8601 does not produce a valid ISO8601 string. This is very confusing, but I doubt PHP would fix that, since it would be a BC break for them.

Answer (score 8):

#### How to convert from ISO 8601 to unixtimestamp :

```
strtotime('2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00');
// Output : 1326883500
```

#### How to convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (timezone server) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00
```

#### How to convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (GMT) :

```
date_format(date_create('@'. 1326883500), 'c') . "\n";
// Output : 2012-01-18T10:45:00+00:00
```

#### How to convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (custom timezone) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500)->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T05:45:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 5):

If you try set a value in datetime-local

```
date("Y-m-d\TH:i",strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46'));

//output : 2010-12-30T23:21
```

Comment: Similar solution is mentioned in the comments given to the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

ISO 8601 is basically represented in PHP as `"Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"`

You can get this value from a constant:

`DateTime::ATOM` - for PHP versions below 7.2 (was removed)

`DateTimeInterface::ATOM` - for PHP versions since 7.2

Comment: `DateTime::ATOM` has not been removed in PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 5):

`$datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z')` should give the proper format, with the "T" separator, "Z" timezone (make sure to convert to UTC first) and microseconds (omit `.u` if you don't intend to support fractional seconds).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532375/65387 for discussion why should use `T`

Answer (score 4):

According to [PHP offcial documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) you can simply format it to:

```
echo $objDateTime->format('c'); // ISO8601 formated datetime
echo $objDateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // Another way to get an ISO8601 formatted string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2010-12-30 23:21:46');

echo $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

Comment: Using `DATE_ATOM` and `c` were already posted on this page years earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To represent the date "2010-12-30 23:21:46" to the ISO 8601 format. Here's how you can do it:

```
<?php
$date = 2010-12-30 23:21:46;
$iso8601_date = date('c', strtotime($date)); // Convert to ISO 8601 format
?>
```

If you are getting date from your Database try:

```
<?php
$date = $row['date']; // Assuming $row['date'] contains "2010-12-30 23:21:46"
$iso8601_date = date('c', strtotime($date)); // Convert to ISO 8601 format
```

Call your Output

```
<?php echo($iso8601_date) ?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. When answering questions please try to provide answers that haven't already been given. You've just submitted a solution that has already been posted.

Comment: Answer already exists

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your timestamps conversion via mutation inside modal like this

```
class YourModal extends Model
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($date)); // ISO 8601 Date Format
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```php
public static function toISO8601(string $dateString): string { 
    $dateTime = new \DateTime($dateString, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.vp');
}
```

Output will be: `2010-12-30T04:56:00.000Z`