# In an ISO 8601 date, is the T character mandatory?

Tags: date, standards, datetime-format, iso

I'm wondering if the following date is ISO8601 compliant :

```
2012-03-02 14:57:05.456+0500
```

(for sure, 2012-03-02T14:57:05.456+0500 is compliant, but not that much human readable !)
IOW, is the T between date and time mandatory ?

Comment: The ISO standard is absurd from a human readability point of view. An underscore (low dash), `_`, would be much better than a `T`: 2012-03-02_14:57:05.456+0500

Comment: The 2019 edition of the ISO-8601 standard made the **`T`** mandatory. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Rodolfo The ISO 8601 standard is primarily for exchanging data-time values, not presentation to human users. You should be localizing for presentation. The title of the ISO 8601 spec includes: *Representations for information interchange*.

Comment: funny that iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html claims: 
"For example, September 27, 2022 at 6 p.m. is represented as 2022-09-27 18:00:00.000."

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's required <strike>unless the "partners in information interchange" agree to omit it</strike>.

Quoting an earlier version of the ISO 8601 standard, section 4.3.2:

> The character [T] shall be used as time designator to indicate the
> start of the representation of the time of day component in these
> expressions. [...]
>
> NOTE  By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange,
> the character [T] may be omitted in applications where there is no
> risk of confusing a date and time of day representation with others
> defined in this International Standard.

Omitting it is fairly common, but leaving it in is advisable if the representation is meant to be machine-readable and you don't have a clear agreement that you can omit it.

But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations):

> In ISO 8601:2004 it was permitted to omit the "T" character by mutual agreement as in "200704051430", but this provision was removed in ISO 8601-1:2019. Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601, but allowed in its profile RFC 3339.

**UPDATE** :  Mark Amery's comment makes a good point, that permission to omit the [T] does not necessarily imply permission to replace it with a space. So this:

```
2012-03-02T14:57:05.456+0500
```

is clearly compliant, and this:

```
2012-03-0214:57:05.456+0500
```

*was* permitted by earlier versions of the standard if the partners agreed to omit the **T**, but this:

```
2012-03-02 14:57:05.456+0500
```

apparently is not (though it's much more readable than the version with the **T** simply omitted).

Personally, if ISO 8601 compliance were required, I'd include the **T**, and if it weren't then I'd use a space (or a hyphen if it's going to be part of a file name).
See also [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) section 5.6, mentioned in [Charles Burns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006233/827263).

Answer (score 24):

That date is not ISO-8601 compliant as Keith Thompson indicated, but it *is* compliant with RFC 3339, a profile of ISO 8601.
Sort of. See NOTE at the bottom of the following text from [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339):

```
date-time       = full-date "T" full-time

  NOTE: Per [ABNF] and ISO8601, the "T" and "Z" characters in this
  syntax may alternatively be lower case "t" or "z" respectively.

  This date/time format may be used in some environments or contexts
  that distinguish between the upper- and lower-case letters 'A'-'Z'
  and 'a'-'z' (e.g. XML).  Specifications that use this format in
  such environments MAY further limit the date/time syntax so that
  the letters 'T' and 'Z' used in the date/time syntax must always
  be upper case.  Applications that generate this format SHOULD use
  upper case letters.

  NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
  Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
  readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
  (say) a space character.
```

Comment: The fact that RFC 3339 allows this is pretty absurd; it seems like the intent of RFC 3339's authors was to create a strictly *stricter* standard than ISO 8601 while ensuring that all RFC 3339 datetimes would still conform to ISO 8601's grammar... but then they randomly decided to torpedo that objective by making the RFC 3339 grammar more permissive than ISO 8601's in this one tiny, pointless way. I don't get it; to me it's such an obviously stupid decision that I can't comprehend how it was made. But it was, whether I like it or not, and so this answer is unfortunately correct.

Comment: I don't think the NOTE is relaxing the grammar of a date-time, but rather pointing out that protocols don't need to use date-time if they'd prefer to use full-date and full-time separately. For example, instead of defining something like `timestamp_header ::= "Timestamp:" date-time`, a protocol could choose to define it like `timestamp_header ::= "Timestamp:" full-date " " full-time`.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO 8601 date and time format is intended to be both human and machine readable. In Structured Query Language (SQL), the standardized programming language that is used for most standard computer databases, the ISO 8601 date and time format in SQL is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", without the "T" preceding the time.

Here is the actual ISO 8601 date and time format specification:
https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Here is the date and time format in SQL:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Oracle seems to use a T, postgres and mysql a space

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/iso-8601-date-time-and-duration-support.html#GUID-20DC09A8-98DF-4473-8077-913D490A969C
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:~:text=ISO%208601%20specifies%20the%20use,as%20some%20other%20database%20systems.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: ok fonud that the link on MySql reports this:

GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO') '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' where it states 
ISO format refers to ISO 9075, not ISO 8601.

Comment: Note that the RFC 3339 standard was issued July 2002. The ISO 8601 standard was updated January 2019, whereas the date and time is represented without the T preceding the time.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` is mandatory in front of *time representations* that could otherwise be mistaken for dates, which will happen for standalone hours or if not using the separator `:`. (Dates do not have an equivalent prefix, although `D` has been proposed and `Y` is supported in ISO 8601-2:2019 for standalone years.)

As the other answers have explained, in a *combined date and time representation*, a separator between the date part and the time part is required in most editions of the standard. Although the time representation cannot be mistaken as a date in this case, its prefix `T` takes over the role of separator in ISO 8601. In RFC 3339, the separator can also be a space or even an underscore `_`.

Most use cases only require the limited scope of [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.html) anyway, so it may be beneficial to claim conformance to that instead of full-blown ISO 8601 Part 1, not to mention Part 2 with 3 levels of [EDTF](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/) etc.

If one wants to claim adherence to ISO 8601 nevertheless, there is a **semantic trick**: Treat the string as two separate entries, one date and one time, separated by a space, both adhering to ISO rules for the respective type.