# Which Java Date format is this "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00+00:00"?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have some data which has date mentioned as "2013-06-30 00:00:00+00:00". I checked the different date formats , however was not able to find this one. Can someone please help ?

Comment: Can you elaborate this date `2013-06-30 00:00:00+00:00`? I think your data is in a excel sheet??

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like ISO 8601

Comment: Hi ... I got this data in a CSV file.

Answer (score 8):

## Optional variation of ISO 8601

As for your question about "what format" this is, technically this format is **an optional variation of ISO 8601**. The [standard allows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) the `T` to be replaced with a SPACE with mutual agreement between the communicating parties.

The use of a SPACE may make the string more readable by humans where proper numeric-savvy fonts are lacking. But strictly speaking this SPACE version is not standard and so the `T` should be included when exchanging data between systems or when serializing data as text.

## Using java.time

Other answers are correct. Here is an easy alternative for parsing.

Your input string nearly complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply fully.

```
String input = "2013-06-30 00:00:00+00:00".replace( " " , "T" );
```

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. These newer classes support ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generatihng strings.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date with the `T` omitted between the date and time (see: [In an ISO 8601 date, is the T character mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531524/in-an-iso-8601-date-is-the-t-character-mandatory))

Comment: Hi ... Yes it looks very similar to the ISO 8601 format, however the data which I have does not have the T. Hence the question :)

Comment: Going through your link it is mentioned that we can skip T (with mutual agreement. Also there is a example mentioned just below which is : 1985-04-12T10:15:30+04:00 . So if we skip the T , the format I have pasted is ISO-8601 ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it should be `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00+0000` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00+00:00`. 
This format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Other different Date formats are

```
yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this answer here because still many people using java 6, 7 in their project.

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        Date paredDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").parse(s);
        cal.setTime(paredDate);
        return cal;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

You can use above format +OO:OO is for timeZone used

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Agreed @OleV.V. I added this answer here because still many people using java 6,7 in their project. So just wanted to give them alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 7+, you can just use `X` pattern string for ISO8601 time zone. For your given String, below will work:

```
LocalDate lt = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Date and time expressed according to ISO 8601 is for example
`2020-10-11T00:00:00+00:00`
or
`2020-10-11T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

Converting the ISO 8601 to `java.util.Date` is bit tricky.
We can use the simpleDateformat API of java for the conversion.

```java
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).