# Convert H:i to ISO 8601 duration standard

Tags: php, datetime

The duration time for a recipe is stored in my database as a string like this: "01:50"
I am trying to convert it to the ISO 8601 duration standard with no success.

This is what I use to call the field and parse it the page:

```
$totalTime = ($extraField->value);
$itempr = "itemprop=\"totalTime\" content=\"$totalTime\"";
```

Like this, it appears in the Google structured data testing tool as "00:50" which is not accepted by Google. From what I understand, it should appear like this: PT1H50M

Has anyone got any ideas on how to convert it to the ISO 8601 format? Please, keep in mind that I am not to keen on development with PHP so be as explanatory as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322285/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-iso-8601-in-php?rq=1

Comment: So, `PT1H50M` is what you want? [You might want to look at this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), or possibly [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Comment: OK, I got it!

$datetime = new DateTime($extraField->value);
$totalTime = $datetime->format('\P\TG\Hi\M');
$itempr = "itemprop=\"totalTime\" content=\"$totalTime\"";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like you already wrote in the comments :

```php
echo (new DateTime('01:50'))->format('\P\TG\Hi\M');
```

or you can convert it already in the database using [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function :

```sql
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('01:50', 'PT%kH%iM');
```