# Change seconds duration to ISO 8601 format

Tags: php, time

How can I convert

> 00:00:46.70

to

> T0M46S

I try

```
$date = new DateTime($time); echo $date->format('\P\TG\Hi\M');
```

but it gives me something like this:

> PT0H00M

Note I want duration... not date!

Comment: @Thilo I should can   do it with native php function...no with a custom function...I saw that post before

Comment: You can leave a comment on the other post, asking if there is such a native php function.

Comment: Looking at another post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19082328/14955) your code should work. Don't you just need to add the part about seconds in the format string?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function, but you can do it with native object DateTime : calculate the duration from midnight to your time.

```php
<?php

    $time     = new DateTime('00:00:46.70');
    $midnight = new DateTime('00:00:00.00');
    $period   = $midnight->diff($time);

    echo $period->format('T%iM%SS'); //output T0M46S

print_r($period);
```

Here is a [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4cb12524ab1cf6db185d59e766d153c6e0474478) to test it

Answer (score 0):

Carbon has the solution

```
function secondsToISO8601Format(int $seconds): string
{
    return Carbon\CarbonInterval::seconds($seconds)->cascade()->spec();
}
```

Comment: I think this one works as expected. Carbon library comes with lots of feature to handle date time easier in PHP. It also remove unnecessary data, i.e. if I pass 3621, it will return PT1H21S, I don't need to check whether there is no minutes data and add logic to remove it manually.