# timeago on my guestbook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timeago

I build a guestbook and i want to add the Timeago-plugin from Yarp (http://timeago.yarp.com/).

I have this javascript on the top of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
</script>
```

Then i have an While-loop there i publish the text from the database. And on each text i have a DATETIME stored.

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $Date; ?>"><?php echo $Date; ?></abbr>
```

So, How do I get it to update the dates?

Comment: What's the question?  What are you trying to update?  The page?  The database?  What does your code do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: It should go automatically. That's why you use it ;)
Is your date formatted in [ISO_8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ?
- If not, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322285/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-iso-8601-in-php)

Comment: What version jQuery do you use? Seems to work fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/K5zMp/