# Using DateTime as a one-liner in PHP

Tags: php, date

A short and simple question which I couldn't really find an answer for.

In procedural PHP I could echo a date

```
echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

In Object oriented PHP I have to use two lines

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
```

Is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: You might be looking for dereferencing which is available in [PHP >= 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Create a DateTime instance using parenthesis and format the result:

   ```
   // requires PHP >= 5.4
   echo (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
   ```
2. You can use the `date_create` function:

   ```
   // date_create is similar to new DateTime()
   echo \date_create()->format('Y-m-d');
   ```

Live Example: https://3v4l.org/fllco

Comment: Wow, the parentheses did it. Thank you!

Comment: What's the backslash for, dear Sir?

Comment: It's an indicator for "global php namespace" and for function it's an optimization for the opcache (performance). You don't need to prefix classes when you are not inside a namespace. Read more about that on SO itself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4790020/3893182

Answer (score 17):

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: What php version does this syntax require?

Comment: you'll need to use PHP >5.4

Comment: I thought about this syntax but I'm using PHP `5.3.3`.

Comment: Consider upgrading your php version if possible, php 5.3.3 is a very old version (22 Jul 2010)

Comment: for the updated ISO8601 format, use eg `echo $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM);` - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322285/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-iso-8601-in-php

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
echo $date = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
```

Object Oriented Style:

```
<?php
try {
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Procedural Style:

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
if (!$date) {
    $e = date_get_last_errors();
    foreach ($e['errors'] as $error) {
        echo "$error\n";
    }
    exit(1);
}

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? The first example does not use custom formatting, the later two are obviously no one-liners