# Retrieve data from a specific sql command in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a database with some temperature data and date. To plot the data I need to convert the datetime into ISO8601.
I found the command to SELECT the correct data and transform them :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datelog`, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') AS date_formatted FROM `tempo` ORDER BY id ASC
```

In phpmyadmin the data show correctly but when I run my php script with the same command it show me the data as they are stored in the DB (e.g: {"datelog":"2016-12-18 11:54:11","donnee":"16.937"}). How can I change that ?

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
define('DB_NAME', 'tempo');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datelog`, \'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ\') AS date_formatted\n" . "FROM `tempo`\n" . "ORDER BY id ASC ";

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could something in concatenation:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datelog`, \'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ\') AS date_formatted\n" . "FROM `tempo`\n" . "ORDER BY id ASC ";
```

Try this if functions:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datelog`, \'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ\') AS date_formatted\n . " " . FROM `tempo`\n . " " . ORDER BY id ASC . ";
```

Comment: Still the same output with this line

Comment: For example, what should be your output?

Comment: It should be something like this : 2016-12-18T00:58:05Z

Comment: Se if this question can help you @eliobou: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322285/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-iso-8601-in-php