# Google Drive Sdk can not set expiration time permissions

Tags: php, api, upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to change the permissions of a Google Drive file with the PHP api client.
Now my problem is that it doesn't set the expiration time. The user permission is successful.

The documentation says that I need to pass the date RFC3339 formatted but I'm doing that.
What's wrong with this code?

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permission->setRole('reader');
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setEmailAddress('someone@gmail.com');
$permission->setExpirationTime(date(DateTime::RFC3339, time() + 86400));

$createPermissions = $service->permissions->create(
    $uploadedFileId,
    $permission
);
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using the ISO format date like the one used in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322285/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-iso-8601-in-php)?

Comment: @DivinsMathew The latest Api Client

Comment: @noogui It's not working, any other idea?

Comment: Where are you seeing in the documentation that you can set an expiration date for permissions via the API?

Comment: @DaImTo Here property name "expirationTime": https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions

Answer (score 0):

1. expirationDate works in Patch or Update
2. this feature has never been available in the free Google accounts and was only added relatively recently to the paid G Suite accounts

and you can check on this link :
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/48687182/cannot-ste-up-temporary-access-to-shared-file-as-there-is-no-such-a-function?hl=en