# Facebook ignores timezone info for non-logged in users on uploaded events with ISO-8601 datetime

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime, timezone, iso8601

Events entered manually into facebook show correct times regardless of logged in state, but events uploaded via an app with datetimes to ISO-8601 (which includes time zone info ie 2013-09-27T13:00:00+01:00) result in facebook assuming event is US based for display.

Once a user is logged in, facebook shows the event correctly using the timezone info.

Its noticeable that manually entered events show a UTC+1 indicator, which does not appear on uploaded events.

Why is facebook ignoring timezone info when a visitor is not logged in, but only for uploaded events?

Is facebook requiring additional timezone data or is this a bug.

Dates are pulled from the dBase and converted to ISO8601 with:
`date("c", strtotime($date))`

then upload function is:

```
        `$page = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}");
        $event_data = array(
            'name' => stripslashes($_POST['name']),
            'description' => stripslashes(preg_replace('/£/', 'Â£', $_POST['description'])),
            'start_time' => $_POST['start_time'],
            'end_time' => $_POST['end_time'],
            'ticket_uri' => $_POST['ticket_uri'],
            'location' => $_POST['location'],
            'location_id' => $_POST['location_id'],
            'no_feed_story' => ($_POST['no_feed_story'] == 1),
            'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'page_id' => $page_id);
     }

    $post = @$facebook->api('/' . $page_id . '/events?fields=name,picture,description,start_time,end_time,ticket_uri,location,no_feed_story', 'POST', $event_data);`
```

When not logged into facebook this will give:
     [When] 27 September at 05:00 until 29 September at 07:00
and once logged in:
     [When] 27 September at 13:00 until 29 September at 15:00

And I am in the UK so viewing from the indicated timezone (UTC+1), my IP location is London.

Editing an uploaded event the timezone is also shown as UTC+01 though that does not display when logged out ??

Some additional info, I`ve downloaded the event feed for the page and note the following errors:

An uploaded datetime of 2013-09-27T13:00:00+01:00 is changed to 2013-09-27T12:00:00+0000
and no time zone is shown, so is it expecting some other timezone data on upload?

I've now added to the code to allow editing of existing events using:

`$post = $facebook->api('/' . $_POST['event_id'] . '/', 'POST', $event_data);`

for update and note that editing a originally manually edited event (that has the timezone) changing the event times using above datetime format, the timezone is retained, changing location has no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled time zone support in the [Facebook app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)?

[image: Facebook Events Timezone setting]

You can read about this more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/).

Comment: Yes, that is enabled, I think its the default setting too.

I`ve also tried with a geographic location set for the event (with lat/long) but still no good.

Comment: I should have added, I have read your link and we are complying with that, in fact if the datetime format is adjusted at all (so not complying with iso8601) an error is returned rejecting the submission.

Comment: Would you please update your question to show the code where the data is being submitted, and exactly how it looks on Facebook when you are done?  Are you sure you aren't just seeing times properly adjusted for the user's time zone?

Comment: What is happening appears to me that facebook is converting entered dates to UTC using timezone info, but on upload is then failing to store the timezone, which would be a facebook bug.

Comment: Is it possible that the upload is fine, but when you *download* the feed you might need to provide the desired timezone for the result?  Can you show how you download it?

Comment: When you view the event is facebook the issue is apparent, for downloading I`m looking at the raw data returned by:
`https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/events?access_token=[access_token]`

Comment: Results returned:

BAD ENTRY
`5 => 
name => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
start_time => 2013-08-21T09:00:00+0000
end_time => 2013-08-21T14:00:00+0000
location => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
id => ddddddddddddd`
GOOD ENTRY (Manually entered)
`6 => 
name => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
start_time => 2013-08-13T10:00:00+0100
end_time => 2013-08-13T15:00:00+0100
timezone => Europe/London
location => Nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
id => dddddddddddd`

Comment: I was just reviewing [the docs on this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events) and it looks like they want the offset without the colon.  `+0100` not `+01:00`.  Either are acceptable by ISO8601, but perhaps facebook is picky.  Can you try formatting it without the colon in the offset and see if that makes a difference?  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3504476/634824) for how to do that in PHP.

Comment: Tried that and the other variations within iso8601 (+01 Z), all are accepted but still have the same result. I`ve raised a bug report.